# Unreadable output

Tags: c, graph, tree

I'm writing a program to translate a given word by following the path to the translation. 
Each letter of the given word represents a specific node.

The output should result in all the words to translate followed by corresponding translations, but I received this as output in stead of:

```
a: 4��t�    xp� t����
an: 4��t�   xp� t����
ant: 4��t�  xp� t����
at: 4��t�   xp� t����
atom: 4��t� xp� t����
no: 4��s�   xp� t����
not: 4��s�  xp� t����
tea: 4��q�  xp� t����
ten: 4��q�  xp� t����
```

main.c:

```
    int main()
    {
        struct Trie* trie = trie_alloc();
        trie_insert_from_file(trie, "dictionary.txt");
        trie_print_mappings(trie);
        trie_free(trie);

        return 0;
    }
```

trie.c:

```
   int trie_insert(Trie* trie, const char* key, const char* value)
    {
        ...
    }

    void trie_insert_from_file(Trie* trie, const char* file_name)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s for reading: %s\n",
                    file_name, strerror(errno));
            return;
        }
        while (!feof(file))
        {
            char key[64];
            char value[64];
            int nb_matched = fscanf(file, "%63[a-z] : %63[a-z]\n", key, value);

            if (nb_matched == 2)
            {
                  trie_insert(trie, key, value);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error while reading file\n");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    static char* str_append_char(const char* str, char c)
    {
        size_t len =  strlen(str);
        char* new_str = malloc(len + 2);
        strcpy(new_str, str);
        new_str[len] = c;
        new_str[len + 1] = '\0';
        return new_str;
    }

    static void trie_print_mappings_aux(Trie* trie, const char* current_prefix)
    {
        if (trie->value != NULL)
            printf("%s: %s\n", current_prefix, trie->value);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < TRIE_NB_CHILDREN; i++)
        {
            Trie* child = trie->children[i];
            if (child != NULL)
            {
                char* child_prefix =
                    str_append_char(current_prefix, trie_get_child_char(i));
                trie_print_mappings_aux(child, child_prefix);
                free(child_prefix);
            }
        }
    }

    void trie_print_mappings(Trie* trie)
    {
        trie_print_mappings_aux(trie, "");
    }
```

trie.h:

```
#define TRIE_NB_CHILDREN 26

typedef struct Trie
{
    char* value;
    struct Trie* children[TRIE_NB_CHILDREN];
} Trie;
```

This doesn't occured when I insert the data mannually with the function *trie_insert* without reading the .txt file with *insert_from_file* .

```
Eg. trie_insert(trie, (const char*)&"ten", (const char*)&"tien");
    trie_insert(trie, (const char*)&"no", (const char*)&"nee");
    trie_insert(trie, (const char*)&"not", (const char*)&"niet" );
...
```

After some research, I believe it could be related to the fact that I'm writing beyond the allowed memory location. But I have no clue where exactly is going wrong.

The functions *insert_from_file*, *str_append_char*,*trie_print_mapping_aux** should work correctly as they were given to me. So the error might be in *trie_insert*, the one I implemented.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wow! Shorten down the code pleas e.

Comment: Everything but the kitchen sink and the two (most likely) relevant functions `trie_insert_from_file` and `trie_print_mappings` ...  And yes, we *do* need to see how you are setting them.

Comment: Character code of the file("dictionary.txt") is not a do not ASCII?

Comment: "dictionnary.txt" contains full of letters, no ASCII code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `trie->value` pointer (in `trie_insert`) to a string stored on the stack (in `trie_insert_from_file` - `char value[64]`).

Variables stored on the stack are "lost" when the function returns - and that means that your trie is pointing somewhere where it shouldn't be (there will be completely different and irrelevant data on the same pointer address).

The solution is to copy the `value` string to the heap:

```
if(*key == '\0')
{
    trie->value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
    strcpy(trie->value, value);
    return 1;
}
```

Just be sure to free the allocated memory when you don't need it.